# Bash for Windows 10 gcc won't compile c files pasted into the root directory

Tags: c, bash, ubuntu, gcc, windows-10

As the title suggests, if I paste a c file written somewhere else into the root directory of the Linux Subsystem, I can't compile it.

I did a test where I made two differently titled hello world programs: one in vi that I can get into from the bash interface, and one elsewhere. When I compiled the one made in vi, it worked fine. Trying to do so for the one made elsewhere (after pasting it into the root directory), however, resulted in this:

```
gcc: error: helloWorld2.c: Input/output error
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Do not change Linux files using Windows apps and tools!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)**

Assuming what you meant by "paste a C file written somewhere else into the root directory of the Linux subsystem" is that you pasted your file into `%localappdata%\lxss`, this is **explicitly unsupported**. Files natively created via Linux syscalls in this area have UNIX metadata, which files natively created with Windows tools don't have.

Use `/mnt/c` (and the like) to access your Windows files from Linux; don't try to modify Linux files from Windows.

---

Quoting from the Microsoft blog linked at the top of this answer (emphasis from the original):

> Therefore, be sure to follow these two rules in order to avoid losing files, and/or corrupting your data:
>
> - **DO store files in your Windows filesystem that you want to create/modify using Windows tools AND Linux tools**
> - **DO NOT create / modify Linux files from Windows apps, tools, scripts or consoles**

Comment: The reason being that windows tools have no concept of Linux file permissions. When you modify a Linux file under `%localappdata%\lxss` with a window file and then save the file, you lose all information regarding Linux file permissions causing the file to 'disappear' on the Linux side of the house. If you want to modify files with windows tools, make a temp copy in say `C:\users\you\tmp`, change the file in your windows program. Then copy the file back through `/mnt/c` to the Linux side from within Linux.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot copy (by default, who knows how Windows `bash` is set up!) files into the root directory! Your `gcc` error is say "no **input** files", so the copy has most likely failed. Copy the files to your home directory instead, for instance:

```
cp helloWorld2.c ~/
```

instead of:

```
cp helloWorld2.c /
```

Comment: If the file didn't exist at all (which is what would be the case had the copy failed as you suggest), that would be ENOENT ("No such file or directory"), not EIO (the "Input/output error" message the OP reports).