# Windows Linux Subsystem - File permissions when edited outside bash

Tags: linux, windows, bash, apache, ubuntu-14.04

I set up the WLS on my machine and configured to be a LAMP server, so that I may potentially be able to edit my repositories locally and use all my dev tools I would normally use on my remote box. I noticed that when I modify a file on my text editor it destroys the file permissions and says the user:group is ???:???

Is there a work around for this?

For example change the apache config to use /mnt/c... instead of /var/www/html. But then can I still assign permissions for www-date to the given directory?

Comment: ...ahh, here we are: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42941023/bash-for-windows-10-gcc-wont-compile-c-files-pasted-into-the-root-directory -- and the Microsoft blog that's the source for the "unsupported and shouldn't be done" assertion: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/

Comment: (aside: This is nothing to do with "outside bash", but is "outside the Linux subsystem" -- you could `exec` an external Linux executable so bash is no longer in memory and it'd still be fine; it's a question of which family of syscalls is active).